# Setting borders to row line in list with Jquerymobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using `jquerymobile`,this code shows list with the colors of `data-theme` (black), how can i set it so those lines will start 2cm from left side and end in 2cm from the end row, I mean so the row wont bi on *all the list row*.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a">
            <li>
                <p><strong>text</strong></p>
                <p class="ui-li-aside"> <strong>text2</strong></p>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS :after pseudo property for this. Write like this:

```
li:after{
 content:'';
 display:block;
 border-bottom:1px solid red;
 margin:0 2cm;
}
```